# How to set path of step Definition file , if my feature file ,stepDefinition file and runner file resides in separate folders?

Tags: cucumber, bdd

I am using maven project for cucumber execution and below is my project explorer view.
[Project Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMmt9.jpg)

I want to instruct "SimpleDataDriverRunner.java" file to execute "SimpleDataDriverStepDefinition.java" class. Both these files are present in different folder structure (as shown in image above).
Below is my runner class

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
    features="dir path\\com\\features\\SimpleDataDriven.feature",
    glue= {"stepDefinition"},
    monochrome=true
    )
```

Can someone please guide me how to achieve this and if this is correct way to deal with multiple runner file and step definition files ?

If there is any BDD cucumber sample project having multiple feature, step Definition and runner files is much appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

I never understood why multiple runners are needed, if is just to run different scenarios it doesn't seem very efficient.
I would use just one runner and select what to run by tags.
Annotate your feature with some tag like `@someTag` and run it.

E.g.:
`mvn test -Dcucumber.filter.tags="@someTag"`

From cucumber documentation:

```
cucumber.features=   # command separated paths to feature files. example: path/to/example.feature, path/to/other.feature  
cucumber.glue=       # comma separated package names. example: com.example.glue
```

Try adding in glue the package for runners also:
`glue= {"stepDefinition", "runner"},`